# How to make the RecyclerView's adapter show add button as last row?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have designed an RecyclerView adapter to display a group of cardviews in a vertical format, and the user has the freedom to add and delete.
the problem is that every time you press the add button, it appears again with the new cardview, and I want to display the add button only once.

Comment: please address your problem in the question title, don't add a generic title, and add a snippet code of your problem

Comment: edit your question , put a good title who describe your issues , and also put your code so we can see the issues.